# How can I simplify writing transactions with macros in clojure?

Tags: clojure, neo4j, macros

I am currently writing an application that uses neo4j. I have a set of functions that I use to interact with the db. Sometimes the functions will be part of a transaction, and sometimes they won't. I'm tasked with writing a bunch of functions with this form:

```
(def some-db-operation 
  ([arg1 arg2] 
    (let [txn (create-txn)]
      (some-db-operation arg1 arg2 txn)
      (close-txn txn)))
  ([arg1 arg2 txn] (do-thing txn arg1 arg2)))
```

Ideally I would like to do this:

```
(def-txn some-db-operation [arg1 arg2 txn]
  (do-thing arg1 arg2 txn))
```

And it would create the first function.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried so far? What problem is preventing you from being able to write this macro?

Answer (score 1):

See these examples here:

- https://github.com/wagjo/borneo/blob/master/src/borneo/core.clj#L296
- http://reference.clojureneo4j.info/clojurewerkz.neocons.rest.transaction.html#var-in-transaction

In general you want to have something like `(in-tx db function)`